# Iterations of datasets

Tags: r, dataset

I've got a question regarding multiple iterations of a dataset. Every month, the file which contains all the employees is made. I want to keep track of changes within the company by making a table with employee changes (new employees, old employees leaving). Each dataset contains information including the persons ID number within the company. Any tips on how I can look at changes of iterations of datasets?
What i've done so far:
I've combined the data in 1 dataset, with an added column specifying the month number. Then, I've looked at the sum of total appereances of each persons ID, but this way I do not necessarily know whether an employee is already gone or just new.

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: Check out `match()` and `%in%`, you will be able to detect the differences in 2 datasets and make a new dataset out of the changes! Without a reproducible example we can't really help beyond that.

Comment: use `dput` along with posting your code to show both an example data set (two for you) and your attempt at solving it.